# Could not resolve 'packages.namniart.com'

Tags: ros, armhf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following the ros installation tutorial for ARM devices, you need to add packages.namniart.com to your sources.list.
http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM

However, it seems to have been down for at least 24 hours. Does anyone know if this was planned downtime, if it was permanently brought down, or if they are just having technical issues? Being unable to install deb packages for ros arm devices is pretty inconvenient...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199429/could-not-resolve-%27packages.namniart.com%27/) by [Jyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2115/jyo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2014-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry; I'm doing some maintenance on my packages server. It should be back online in a few days.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-15**:
As per http://answers.ros.org/question/199410/unable-to-setup-sourceslist-arm/ , I'm aware that the domain is expired and I'm working on renewing it. My provider is here in California, and they had a pretty significant power outage last week, so they're not responding quickly.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-15**:
The standard ROS binaries are compiled for x86, so it isn't possible to use them on ARM.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-17**:
I've renewed the domain and the DNS records are updated. It may take up to 24 hours for the DNS changes to propagate.

**Comment by [Neuromorphic](https://answers.ros.org/users/13466/neuromorphic/) on 2015-01-07**:
Your time and effort is much appreciated, thank you.